# Vim Statusline colors not appearing

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, statusline

I want my vim statusline to have some color and I can't figure out why it does not with this code:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline+=%1*\ %f\ %*
set statusline+=%2*\ %<%F%*
set statusline+=%2*%m%*
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%1*%=%5l%*
set statusline+=%2*/%L%*
hi User1 guifg=#eea040 guibg=%222222
hi User2 guifg=%dd3333 guibg=%222222
```

This is what it looks like currently:
[image: Vim Image]

How can I

1. Get color onto the filename etc. and
2. Remove the whitespace between the left and right side?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

according to `:h gui-colors`

```
    You can also specify a color by its Red, Green and Blue values.
    The format is "#rrggbb", where
        "rr"    is the Red value
        "gg"    is the Green value
        "bb"    is the Blue value
    All values are hexadecimal, range from "00" to "ff".  Examples: >
  :highlight Comment guifg=#11f0c3 guibg=#ff00ff
```

You need to change `guibg=%222222` to `guibg=#222222`. It surprises me you didn't get any error, i thought you are running a terminal vim until i saw gvim tag.

You can remove `%=` area by changing guifg of StatusLine to guibg of your `User#`.

To fix problem 1:

```
hi User1 guifg=#eea040 guibg=#222222
hi User2 guifg=#dd3333 guibg=#222222
```

To fix problem 2:

```
    hi StatusLine guifg=#222222
```

Comment: You can use `:h gui-colors` in terminal vim as well as gui vim. Check out `:h termguicolors`

Answer (score 0):

You need these lines. Put them in your `vimrc` and restart vim (`:xa` and `$ vim`). Or you can put them in your `vimrc` and source it (`:so %`) twice, once to get the vimrc updated and once again to set up the colors according to the `:h autocmd`.

```
set termguicolors
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%1*\ %f\ %*
set statusline+=%2*\ %<%F%*
set statusline+=%2*%m%*
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%1*%=%5l%*
set statusline+=%2*/%L%*

augroup statusline
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter,ColorScheme * hi User1 guifg=#eea040 guibg=#222222
    autocmd VimEnter,ColorScheme * hi User2 guifg=#dd3333 guibg=#222222
augroup END
```

### Explanation:

- The `:h termguicolors` part is just there in case you're using a terminal vim.
- I took the liberty to change the `+=` from the first line to `=` because otherwise everytime you sourced your `vimrc` you would've added to (not overwritten) your statusline.
- You need to wrap the `:h hi` commands in `:h :augroup`. Otherwise, it won't work when you manually change the colorscheme with `:colorscheme default` etc.
- You had some typos. You used `%` instead of `#` to represent hex colors.